# Router.go() does not working when adding extra path

Tags: meteor, iron-router, router

I have created Router in my router.js like this :

```
Router.go("students/add/:id?", {
    name:"students",
    progress: {
        enabled: false
    },
    fastRender: true
});
```

In My add new student page i have this code in my submit event to redirect on edit mode page

```
Router.go("students/add/" + studentId);
```

But this is not working. It does not redirect to edit page. Any idea about this?

Comment: shouldn't it be `Router.go("/students/add/" + studentId);`?

Comment: @pahan strange. It's working !

Comment: what's working adding a slash?

Comment: @pahan yes adding a slash it's working.

Answer (score 1):

it should be  `Router.go("/students/add/" + studentId);` (with slash)

Answer (score 1):

The good way to write your router.go in Iron router is:

> Router.go('post.show', {_id: 1}, {query: 'q=s', hash: 'hashFrag'});

So your Router.go will be like

> Router.go('students', {id?:studentId});